# Interesting vs tractable PhD topics

Tags: phd, thesis, projects

When one starts a PhD, should it be based upon interest or tractability of the project? If a project fails is switching advisors a reasonable option within the same department?

I have a couple options for PhD, one is an area I am more interested in but it's a more open ended problem with potentially less straightforward solutions. It also gives a background in more areas I am interested in learning and more industry applicable(focused on making novel system which works).

The other I don't think I want to work on for 4 years but probably will be more straightforward, it's also less useful to industry(I think) and more theoretical in nature. It is a continuation(mostly) of what I already know.

I'm not sure what to do, I have no interest in staying in academics so a PhD which is more focused on an applied topic which could be used to spin up a company is a lot more interesting to me but I obviously don't want it to fail.

Comment: What is your motivation for doing a PhD?

Comment: It sounds like you should just do a start-up if you're not that interested in doing research? If your main goal is to do a start-up then why wait 5 years to do it? You should also be aware that earning PhD does not imply you will make a high wage, in fact, in the long run, economically you might be better off just not doing a PhD.

Comment: I don't have all the skills for a startup and the PhD will cover additional classes and give me more hands on experience with a few systems I wouldn't normally have access to. I'm interested in research but I want it to be transferable to a physical product.

Comment: So why is the more straightforward/theoretical topic even an option? It seems entirely disconnected from your motivation.

Comment: The _more theoretical_ project is more straightforward?  That's a new one.

Comment: The bar for theoretical projects is arbitrarily low in so far as you can nearly an unlimited number of assumptions. On the other hand if you want to build a system which has predefined goals it's much harder

Answer (score 3):

You give a false dichotomy, because you should be doing a project that you are interested in and one that can be completed. There's no point in choosing a topic you hate working on for 5 years but is solvable just as there's no point in choosing a topic you're passionate about but not even those who have studied it for decades could solve (possible, but *highly* unlikely). Therefor, the answer to your question is to choose a solvable problem that you are interested in.

However, if you're interested in living in a binary world, then choose a project that is tractable and you hate. If you are concerned about getting a PhD, then it's better to complete a project and receive the degree than to work hard on a problem and receive no degree.

Comment: Hmm I see your point, I think the real question is - suppose I work for 2 years on a problem and don't make much progress but can exit with a second MS. Should this be viewed as a failure or not? If I am getting something from the PhD process itself, independent of the degree it seems that should be factored in.

Comment: Also what about changing advisors if it goes bad? Doable?

Comment: What does it matter to us if you gaining a second masters is considered to be a failure or not? It’s really up to you to define what you consider to be success and what you don’t. Second, changing advisors is a serious thing you shouldn’t take lightly. What would be the reason you would be switching advisors? Furthermore, how do you know you’ll be able to switch to the advisor you want when you come to the decision to switch? And what would you define “goes bad” to be?

Comment: If the projects ended up as either intractable or unsupported, I would think switching advisors would be a reasonable course of action. In the departments own handbook they said switching advisors was fairly common within the first few years.....

Comment: It’s not uncommon, but that doesn’t take away from the seriousness of the implications in doing so. For example, you may end up on a new project you don’t like, you may end up with a prof who doesn’t tailor to your style, you may end up burning more time than you’d like, you may be in a position where what you think will happen doesn’t pan out the way you’d like, you may end up developing skills you don’t want to be developing. I say all of this because it sounds like you haven’t considered the implications too carefully of switching advisors.

Comment: _choose a solvable problem that you are interested in_ — If you ever figure out how to identify such problems, please let me know.  (I've always worked on multiple interesting problems at once, in the hopes that _some_ of them might be solvable.)

Comment: @JeffE I find that hard to believe if you're a full professor haha! You must have identified a problem, at least have been somewhat interested in it, done research, and published your results at least once to gain tenure. If you’re only researching problems you’re uninterested in AND publishing, then I applaud your perseverance for staying in the game for so long.

Comment: @GrayLiterature Oh, no, I've found **lots** of interesting open problems to work on.  I made progress on enough of them to be successful, but most of them are still open and interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good PhD adviser will guide you to a project that is interesting and doable. Look for potential thesis advisers and see what their past students have done.